# Match repeating groups with regex with optional parameter in .NET

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I need to validate a filtering input with a regex that will be used for a `[RegularExpression]` attribute on a `Filter` field in a class used a input model. The input has the following format:

```
[property]~[predicate]~[value]
```

For example:

```
lastname~eq~'John'
```

and also multiple filtering can be applied n times:

```
[property]~[predicate]~[value]~[logicaloperator]~[property]~[predicate]~[value] ...
```

For example:

```
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~'John'~or~firstname~eq~'Jane'
```

I have to make sure that if logical operators are used then they are followed by the same pattern. I tried using named groups and lookbehinds but I couldn't get it to work properly.

I've created the following regex :

```
((((\w+)~(\blt\b|\blte\b|\beq\b|\bgt\b|\bgte\b|\bneq\b|\bcontains\b)~(.\w+.))(~(\bor\b|\band\b)~)?((\w+)~(\blt\b|\blte\b|\beq\b|\bgt\b|\bgte\b|\bneq\b|\bcontains\b)~(.\w+.))?)+)
```

I cannot get it to match only when the input is valid. The general pattern of the groups that I've tried to implement is:

```
(main group-
 (property group-any word)~(predicate group-list of operators)~(value -any value)
)
(~(logic operator)~)
(main group)
```

Targeted behavior:

Valid input:

```
lastname~eq~'Doe'                                                      -> should match
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~'John'                              -> should match
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~'John'~or~firstname~eq~'Jane'        -> should match
```

Invalid input:

```
lastname~eq~                                          ->should not match
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq                    ->should not match
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~John~              ->should not match
lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~John~or~           ->should not match
```

Any ideas how to make this work ?

Comment: You say `lastname~eq~'Doe'~and~firstname~eq~'John'~or~firstname~eq~'Jane` is a match, does it mean the `'` can be missing at the end? Why do you use a `.` to match the qualifier? Can there be `'` or `"`, or more chars?

Comment: In general yes but I've left the single quote out by mistake and just fixed it. The value for [value] can be anything alphanumeric. I've put the . to match if the client sends ' or " yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\w+~(?:lte?|n?eq|gte?|contains)~['"][^'"]+['"](?:~(?:and|or)~\w+~(?:lte?|n?eq|gte?|contains)~['"][^'"]+['"])*$
```

Or,

```
^(?:\w+~(?:lte?|n?eq|gte?|contains)~['"][^'"]+['"](?:~(?:and|or)~(?!$)|$))+$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%7E%28%3F%3Alte%3F%7Cn%3Feq%7Cgte%3F%7Ccontains%29%7E%5B%27%22%5D%5B%5E%27%22%5D%2B%5B%27%22%5D%28%3F%3A%7E%28%3F%3Aand%7Cor%29%7E%28%3F!%5Cr%3F%24%29%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29%29%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=lastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7Efirstname%7Eeq%7E%27John%27%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7Efirstname%7Eeq%7E%27John%27%7Eor%7Efirstname%7Eeq%7E%27Jane%27%0D%0A%0D%0AInvalid%20input%3A%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7E%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7Efirstname%7Eeq%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7Efirstname%7Eeq%7EJohn%7E%0D%0Alastname%7Eeq%7E%27Doe%27%7Eand%7Efirstname%7Eeq%7EJohn%7Eor%7E&o=m).

Note that the `$` is preceded with `\r?` in the regex demo because the string is a multiline string with CRLF line endings, and `RegexOptions.Multiline` option is enabled.

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `~` - a `~` char
- `(?:lte?|n?eq|gte?|contains)` - a predicate pattern (`lt`, `lte`, `gt`, `gte`, `neq`, `eq`, `contains`
- `~` - a `~` char
- `['"][^'"]+['"]` - a `'` or `"`, then one or more chars other than `'` and `"` and then a `"` or `'`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `~(?:and|or)~` - `~`, `and` or `or`, and a `~` char
  - `\w+~(?:lte?|n?eq|gte?|contains)~['"][^'"]+['"]` - described above
- `)*` - zero or more repetitions
- `$` - end of string.